# Nested loops and conditionals in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have trouble in using nested loops and conditionals in `pgfplots`. I'm familiar with the `\foreach` and `\ifthenelse` commands, but do not work well with `pgfplots`. For example, in the following I want to fill some region, while other region empty. Some kind of conditional is needed to decide the region and conditionally fill them. How to resolve this problem?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,disabledatascaling]

    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}
    {
      \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9}
      {
          \addplot[mark color=black,mark=o] coordinates {(\x,\y)};
          \ifthenelse {\x < \y}
             \draw[fill]  (\x,\y) circle (2pt);
      }
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Why do you need pgfplots for this? Remove `\addplot`,axis environment and it should work. Pgfplots does not work like TikZ syntax hence the problem.

Comment: As @percusse says, this looks like a case of picking the wrong tool. The `pgfplots` package is good for plotting data sets containing multiple points, not for lots of single points (you will get 100 plots here!). Could you explain in more detail what the output should look like?

Answer (score 3):

You can use pure TikZ for the resulting image (except the axis lines) as

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}
    {
      \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9}
      {
          \ifnum\x<\y\draw[fill]  (\x,\y) circle (2pt);\fi
      }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wish to use `pgfplots` for some other reason, then you need to make sure that `pgfplots` understand what you want to plot. TikZ commands are not directly drawn but they are collected and handled after everything is parsed inside the axis environment. Therefore when pgfplots read the TikZ plots the commands need to be expanded already.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=10,ymax=10]
\addplot[draw=none,no marks] coordinates {(0,0) (10,10)};
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}
    {
      \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9}
      {\ifnum\x<\y
         \begingroup\edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand\draw[fill]  (axis cs:\x,\y) circle (2pt);}\temp
       \fi
      }
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]